# Adding and removing a tag on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the color of a specific word inside a text of an element. I tried adding and removing span tags to change the style of the word, but I can't remove it after. Here's the code I tried

```
function changeColor(unit){
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML.replace('/<span id="highlighted">(.*)<\/span>/g','$1');
document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByClassName("label")[0].innerHTML.replace(unit,'<span id="highlighted">' + unit + '</span>');
}
```

The text looks like this `"°C,kW/h,cm"`.

What is happening right now is everytime the function is called, span tags are added but never removed. How can I achieve this with Javascript/JQuery?

Desired behavior :

When the function is called with say `"cm"` as parameter. I want the string to become `"°C,kW/h,<span id=highlighted>cm</span>"`. Now if the function is called again with `"kW/h"`, I want the string to become `"°C,<span id=highlighted>kW/h</span>,cm"`

Comment: show us the html too. Describe the requirement well..

Comment: What exactly you wanna achieve?

Comment: `'/<span id="highlighted">(.*)<\/span>/g'` is a string, you need a RegEx at this point. Remove the `'`s.

Comment: see the edit showing desired behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery you can use [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

**Try**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label span").contents().unwrap()
});
```

```css
label {color:green}
#highlighted{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>°C,<span id=highlighted>kW/h</span>,cm</label>
```

Comment: @loli If you are going to accept this solution keep in mind that the erroneous line with `replace` can be removed as it is redundant.

Comment: @Xufox I think using `.replace` in the HTML is not a good idea, even deletes all events that this could have. The best way is to modify the Dom with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.replace('/<span id="highlighted">(.*)<\/span>/g','$1')
```

to

```
.replace(/<span id="highlighted">(.*)<\/span>/g,'$1')
```

The first one is a string, the second one a RegEx and you need the latter.

See how [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works. The first argument is either a string or a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my no-jQuery solution:

- Make 3 spans (s1, s2, s3)
- Change the color style depending on the unit input

And so:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script>
  function changeColor(unit) {
    var allUnits = [ '°C', 'kW/h', 'cm' ];
    for (var i = 0; i < allUnits.length; i++) {
      if (unit == allUnits[i]) 
        document.getElementById('s'+(i+1)).style = 'color:#00FFFF';
      else
        document.getElementById('s'+(i+1)).style = 'color:#000000';
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    changeColor('kW/h');
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="s1">°C</span>,<span id="s2">kW/h</span>,<span id="s3">cm</span>
</body>
</html>
```